Hilbert-Poincare series of a quadratic algebra
Given a graded quadratic algebra, when the associated Hilbert-Poincaré series is a quotient of integer polynomials where the numerator has negative roots and the denominator positive roots? It is known that the exterior and symmetric algebras generated by certain Hecke solutions to the Yang-Baxter equation verify this property, is that the most general case?

I think there's a typo: is one instance of numerator meant to read denominator?

Ah, yes, naturally, thanks for pointing it out!
